# How to use RF24 to talk to nRF24L01+ on regular PC (Linux) over USB?

Tags: linux, arduino, x86, usb

As I do not have RPi I would love to use my regular PC to talk to nRF24L01+ (connected to Arduino and then to PC with USB). Something like IP over serial.

PC -> USB -> Arduino + nRF24L01+

Is it possible or I need RPi?

I have tried to compile tmrh20 RF24 on Ubuntu x86:
make -B RF24_SPIDEV=1
but it gives me error:
RF24_config.h:58:23: fatal error: Arduino.h: No such file or directory
(they are in regular Ubuntu place).

Comment: It looks I was completely wrong, and should look into SLIP.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to do the same thing with not much luck. However, I can tell you that you'll need to run

```
./configure --driver=SPIDEV
```

This should get you past your error. However, I'm still having issues when trying to run make:

```
[Linking]
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-soname,librf24.so.1 -Ofast -Wall -pthread  -o librf24.so.1.1.7 RF24.o spi.o gpio.o compatibility.o interrupt.o
RF24.o: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [librf24.so.1.1.7] Error 1
```